# Docusign API embedded signature smsAuthentication not sent

Tags: docusignapi

I have developed a working embedded signature ceremony using a demo docusign account. I'm trying to add smsAuthentication to it.

Here is an abstract of my envelope creation API call :

```
"recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "XXXXXXXX",
                "clientUserId": XXXXXXXX,
                "recipientId": XXXXXXXX,
                "name": "XXXXXXXX",
                "idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",
                "smsAuthentication": {
                    "senderProvidedNumbers": [
                        "+33XXXXXXXX"
                    ]
                },
```

I then retrieve a working embedded signature URL, but no confirmation SMS is sent when I start signing.

When sending an envelope using the manual form on the demo account, the SMS is correctly sent. I've inspected the API call made by the manual form and it is similar to mine (it uses `"idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",`), apart from the fact that it is not embedded (no `clientUserId` specified).

Is there another required step in making an embedded signature use SMS auth ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed to set one property "requireIdLookup": "true", the code should look like

```
"idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",
            "requireIdLookup": "true",    <----- missing
            "smsAuthentication": {
               "senderProvidedNumbers": [
                   "xxx-xxx-xxxx"
               ]
            }
```